# Pebble C TupletCString compile error

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have an issue compiling my pebble watchapp. I am trying to send strings to the Pebbl eJS script on the phone lihe this:

```
Tuplet password_tuple = TupletCString(PASSWORD_KEY, password_str);
Tuplet email_tuple = TupletCString(EMAIL_KEY, email_str);
```

The compiler error is: (they both error out like this, this is just one of the lines of output below)

```
./src/app_test.c:84:25: error: the address of 'email_str' will always evaluate as 'true'   [-Werror=address]
```

email_str and password_str are defined at the top of the program, like this:

```
static char email_str[30];
static char password_str[30];
#define PASSWORD_PKEY (int32_t)21
#define EMAIL_PKEY (int32_t)20
```

Does anyone notice anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

@ismail-badawi answer is very correct.

Pebble now recommends that you use [`dict_write_cstring`](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___dictionary.html#ga015dfe89d0ee2f8b4e16ddda21bcf556).

```
dict_write_cstring(&iter, SOME_STRING_KEY, string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it's certainly not obvious, but it turns out it's because `TupletCString` is a macro, and it'll expand to an expression that contains `email_str ? strlen(email_str) + 1 : 0` as a subexpression, and this is what causes the error, because `email_str` can't be null and so the comparison isn't doing anything.

I found [this thread on the Pebble forums](http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/10690/the-address-of-will-always-evaluate-as-true) with an explanation. The suggested fix is to define your own macro that doesn't have a conditional, e.g.

```
#define MyTupletCString(_key, _cstring) \
((const Tuplet) { .type = TUPLE_CSTRING, .key = _key, .cstring = { .data = _cstring, .length = strlen(_cstring) + 1 }})
```